# Where are components (dll) references stored in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I have dlls in bin directory. I can't see where they are referenced in either solution or web.config files. So where are the references stored ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer depends on if your project is a *Web Site* or a *Web Application*. In a Web *Site* all the assemblies in the bin directory are automatically referenced. A Web *Application* has the project references that you are looking for.

Comment: Need to add *.refresh files in Bin directory to source control. They are required to automatically copy DLLs from NuGet packages to Bin.

Answer (score 5):

When working on a previously developed ASP.NET "WebSite" project in VS2012, I figured out how to find them (and thus add/remove/update them).

1. Over in the Solution Explorer, right-click the name of the project (the project will have the wire-frame globe icon next to it)
2. Click **"Property Pages"** (**NOT** Properties Window). It will appear in its own separate (floating) window frame.
3. Now just left-click the item **"References"** at the top of the list to the left. That's it! You can now add, delete, and update any reference(s) associated with your WebSite project.

Comment: Does anybody know where these changes in Property Pages get stored (so they can be checked in to source control), please? I am dealing with a legacy asmx web service, and I cannot see a specific file where these changes can be found. All I see is that some dlls get copied into Bin directory, and that's not something I would wish to push to TFS...

Comment: @Victoria, need to check in *.refresh files in Bin directory.

Answer (score 4):

If web app project or MVC, right-click and select unload project.  Then right click again and select edit .  If you dig through the XML, you will find the collection of project references and other DLL references to MS or other assemblies.

Answer (score 3):

If you actually have them *referenced*, they should be "stored" in the project files (*.csproj for C#, *.vbproj for Visual Basic).

Answer (score 2):

In the case of an ASP.NET **web site**, the references are stored in the web.config file.

I've removed most of the assemly references, but one of my old web sites has things like this:

```
<compilation debug="true">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Comment: These are not actual references in the since you think they are. You can add a web.config with the above XML, and still not resolve any of these references. (unless they are GAC'd)