# How do I maintain references when cloning an ASP.NET Website (as opposed to web app)?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

There's a list of references listed in the Property Pages for an ASP.NET website. Where is this list stored? When a reference is added, the DLL is added to the bin, but this list doesn't seem to be a list of DLLs in the bin folder.

We are having trouble needing to re-add references to a project after pulling it down from source control on a new machine, and trying to determine what needs to be included in source control to prevent the need to re-add everything.

Comment: Are talking about the WEB.CONFIG file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are components (dll) references stored in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469268/where-are-components-dll-references-stored-in-asp-net)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-asp-net-web-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to my primary problem of cloning the solution and not needing to re-do all of the references was to ensure that the *.dll.refresh files are in source control. Thank you to Mohsin for his possible duplicate post, which had a reference to this in a comment for the excepted answer.